# Suppose $f$ is a function whose domain includes the interval $(1,3)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}f(x) \neq 7$. Let $b_n=f(3-\frac{n}{n+1})$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a function whose domain includes the interval $(1,3)$ and
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}f(x) \neq 7$.

Let $b_n=f(3-\frac{n}{n+1})$. Then $b_n \nrightarrow 7$.

This statement is false, but I'm not sure why?

Comment: If the existence of the limit $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)$ is not assumed, then the statement is indeed false. Consider the function $f$ which takes the value $0$ on $(1,2]$ and $7$ on $(2,3)$, for instance.

Comment: As an extreme case, can you imagine a function $f$ for which $f(3-n/(n+1)) = 7$ for all $n$ but for which $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) \neq 7$? Start by plotting the points of the form $(3-n/(n+1), 7)$ and let $f$ vary wildly in between such points ...

Comment: I think I understand - to check my understanding, since (3-n/(n+1)) is monotone and converging to 2, it makes the question visually equivalent to $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}f(x)$, which can exist, correct?